# .Net core1.0 Error trying to activate my repository

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've created a solution which includes an MVC project and 2 .net core class library projects. 1 for the service layer and 1 for the repository layer. I have successfully wired the interfaces through the layers. but at the point in program class when it tries to perform `host.Run();` It errors. with this:
`InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'VisualRepository.VisualJobsDbContext' while attempting to activate 'VisualRepository.RecruiterRepository'.`

This is the start of my DBcontext Class:

```
public partial class VisualJobsDbContext : DbContext
{
    private IConfigurationRoot _config;

    public VisualJobsDbContext() { }

    public VisualJobsDbContext(IConfigurationRoot config, DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
        _config = config;
    }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);

        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_config["ConnectionStrings:VisualJobsContextConnection"]);
    }
```

This is the start of my Recruiter Repository

```
public class RecruiterRepository : GenericRepository<VisualJobsDbContext,Agent>, IRecruiterRepository
{
    private VisualJobsDbContext _context;

    public RecruiterRepository(VisualJobsDbContext context) : base(context)
    {
        _context = context;

    }
```

both of these sit in the repository layer and I suspect its failing because I haven't set either of these to **'New'** anywhere.

Up in the startup class of the MVC project in the ConfigureServices method I have:

```
 services.AddSingleton(_configuration);
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(_configuration);

        services.AddLogging();
        services.RegisterServices();

        services.AddMvc();
```

Where Services.RegisterServices is a method in the service layer that registers my interfaces into the di container including adding the repository container.
I suspect I need to register VisualJobsDBContext in the mvc layer somehow, but I was hoping that I could keep it registered in the repository layer some how since I dont want a direct connection through to this layer from MVC. Can anybody point me in a sample of how to register the my repositories in the repository layer.

In my Repository Layer when I register my interfaces I currently have the following code :

```
public static class RepositoryCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection RegisterRepositoryServices(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped<IRecruiterRepository, RecruiterRepository>();

        return services;
    }
}
```

so I was hoping I could do something here such as services.AddDbContext(.... but I cant seem to get the signature right.

Comment: Typically I register services in one place, not by scattering the registration methods throughout my layers.  I think that having your repository layer have a method to do DI defeats the purpose of Inversion of Control.  Anyway, what do you mean you can't get the signature right?  Are you following the example here?  https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/dependency-injection.html#using-framework-provided-services

Comment: @stephen.vakil Thanks. Strange I first did it as per the link and that's what gave the error. I've since unloaded and reloaded the solution, added the line again as per your link and it has worked. I have another issue, but this one is solved. thanks